# C struct memory layout offsets

Tags: c, memory, struct

I am dealing with structs like the following:

```
struct s1 {
  struct s1 *next;
  char a[64];
  char b[64];
  struct s2 *other;
};

struct s2 {
  uint32_t x;
  uint32_t y;
}
```

Having obtained a pointer to `b` of `s1`, I'm trying to use pointer arithmetic to access the members of `s1->other`. I've tried the following:

```
// Assuming we have the following
struct s1 *p1 = ...
char *b = p1->b;

// Offset to get to s2
struct s2 *p2 = (struct s2*) b + 64;

// Access members
uint32_t result = p2->x;
```

I don't think padding is the problem since I'm starting from `b`.

Comment: Even without the mandatory [mcve], this code invokes undefined behaviour. It is a clear **don't**. Wildly casting pointers like that violates the effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not completely convinced the posted code violates strict aliasing as a `char *` is used.  I have, however, no need at all to be convinced the posted code is a very, very bad approach.

Comment: why don't you use unions? What C dialect, compiler and platform do you use?

Comment: Part of what you want is provided by `offsetof`- why don't you use that?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6 ff. Briefly: Whlie a cast **to** `char *` and accessing as `char` is fine, it is no general allowance to do the opposite. Modern compilers will exploit this.

Comment: @PeterJ: C is a standardised language. Without further information, we have to assume standard C, i.e. C11 (C99 is mostly backwards compatible). And the platform is irrelevant for the same reason.

Comment: @tofro: `offsetof` will not really help here.

Comment: What is wrong with just `struct s2 *p2 = p1->other` ?

Comment: One more improvement, use sizeof() to calculate the address of the field other from the field b. Like this  struct s2 * p2 = (struct s2*)(b + sizeof(char)*64). Even if we all know that sizeof(char) = 1

Comment: @Olaf Why would `struct s2 *p2 = (struct s2*)(b - offsetof(s1, b) + offsetof (s1, s2)` not give a valid pointer to `s2`?

Comment: @tofro: Read about undefined behaviour and the effective type rule. You'd be surprised what a modern compiler like gcc might generate from this code.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not surprised - There's nothing in above code that would point to anything with an aliased pointer. If you think otherwise, please explain. I'm really interested.

Comment: @tofro: Assuming the code should be `(struct s2*)(b + 64)`, it still generates a pointer to the not defined type. Additionally it generates a pointer past the object. There is a lot of explanations here about 6.5p6/7. I'd recommend reading them. Comments are not the place for extended discussion and I'm not in the mood to re-iterate this over and over again.

Comment: @Olaf assume you've just notched into the wrong slot. If `offsetof` is defined to return the offset between base pointer and member pointer (which it is), then this is also true the other way round.

Comment: @tofro: it does not say you are allowed to use a different type for the access than the original object type the member passed to `offsetof` has. A common missconcepotion, yet a missconception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
struct s2 *p2 = (struct s2*) b + 64;
```

should be changed to:

```
struct s2 *p2 = *(struct s2**) (b + 64);
```

Parentheses were added because cast has higher precedence than `+`.

Double pointer was used instead of regular one because, as @M.M said, the object at `b + 64` is a `struct s2 *` (not `struct s2`).

---

#### Obligatory disclaimer:

I assume you do it for practice only.

You shouldn't use such tricks in real projects. If you absolutely have to, at least use `offsetof` to avoid any potential padding problems.

Comment: The code invokes UB. No further research necessary (or helpful).

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @HolyBlackCat, the obvious issue is precedence of type cast over the `+`-operator, such that `(struct s2*) b + 64` is equivalent to `(struct s2*) (b + 64*sizeof(struct s2))`.

Anyway, I'd avoid to use pointer arithmetics to obtain the next data member, because of possible padding issues and because of the hard coded `64`. (The compiler is free to add padding bytes, so you can't rely on the `64`, but I think you are aware of this).

I'd rather use `offsetof` to get a pointer to the `struct s1`-object to which the respective `b` belongs, and then simply use `->other` to get the `struct s2`-pointer:

```
struct s1 {
    struct s1 *next;
    char a[64];
    char b[64];
    struct s2 *other;
};

struct s2 {
    uint32_t x;
    uint32_t y;
};


int main() {
    struct s2 os2 = { 10, 20 };
    struct s1 os1 = { NULL, "asdf", "asdf", &os2 };

    char *b = os1.b;

    struct s1 *ps1 = (struct s1*)(b - offsetof(struct s1, b));

    struct s2 *p2 = ps1->other;

    // Access members
    uint32_t result = p2->x;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
// Offset to get to s2
struct s2 *p2 = (struct s2*)b + 64; // Wrong!!  casting b as a s2*
                                      // you are getting the address of
                                      // the 65tth element of an array of s2
                                      // starting at b.

struct s2* p2 = (struct s2*)((char*)&(p1->b) + 64); // note the char* cast here.
                                      // it will make this work even when b 
                                      // is not a char array
```